# JavaCC regular expression [#xC0-#xD6]

Tags: java, regex, unicode, escaping, javacc

I want to convert `[#xC0-#xD6]` to `JavaCC` syntax. I've tried with `["\uC0"-"\uD6"]`, but i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid escape character.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
[\\u00C0-\\u00D6]
```

quotes are not needed inside character class.

Comment: I have tried ["\u00C0"-"\u00D6"] and that works correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the escape character. Java doesn't know what `"\u"` means so you need `"\\u"` instead.